# Reset / Unpin all items in Windows 8 Start Screen quickly

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

I got 200+ shortcuts pinned on the Windows 8 start screen by some rogue program.

It would be a pain to right-click every item and then click `Unpin` to remove them:

[image]

Is there a way to remove all the items from the start screen easily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open `Command Prompt (Admin)` by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Copy these lines:

   ```
   del %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\appsFolder.itemdata-ms
   del %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\appsFolder.itemdata-ms.bak
   tskill explorer
   ```
3. Right-click in Command Prompt and select `Paste`:

   [image]
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. You're done. Now the Windows 8 start screen will reset to its original state:

[image]

Comment: This works great to reset it to the default, but do you have any idea how I could set it to entirely blank?