# Why are my Administrative Tools not showing after my upgrade from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-8, start-menu, windows-8-upgrade

I'm trying to show my Administrative Tools in the Start menu of my newly upgraded Windows 8 Pro computer. It was initially on Windows 7 Pro.

I have gone into *Settings » Tiles » Show Administrative Tools* via the Start Menu, however that shows nothing. I can right click the Start Menu area and go to *All Apps » Control Panel* (which brings me back to the desktop) and then go to *Administrative Tools*.

Any other solutions for making the Administrative Tools show up?

Comment: Are you sure they didn't get added to the Start Screen? Did you try scrolling all the way to the right?

Comment: Yes and there is nothing. What I find odd is that the Tile is set to Yes on Show Administrative Tools and it doesn't show that tile. I guess thats more of my concern

Comment: Hmm, maybe unchecking that option and performing a [Start Screen reset](http://superuser.com/questions/499093/reset-unpin-all-items-in-windows-8-start-screen-quickly) will help, if you're willing to try it.

Comment: Tried that and no difference just deleted all my icons which is fine I just want the Start Menu to behave how its designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found to this was going into the Start Menu->General->Refresh your PC without affecting your files.

After that the tools showed back up.

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1 - Via File Explorer

Open file explorer and go to

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools
```

That will bring you directly to Administrative Tools.

## Step 2 - Desktop Shortcut

Continue from step 1, in file explorer location bar, holding/pressing the left most icon, drag and drop it on to your desktop.

That create a desktop shortcut for you.

## Step 3 - Pin to start

Right click on that desktop shortcut, then select `Pin to Start`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Win + I to get the "Settings" charm.
2. Move the slider under "Show administrative tools" to the right (until you see "Yes").